# How to categories applications in Activities Overview?

Tags: gnome, configuration, customization, activities-overview

I have seen that some applications are in little sub-categories in the Activities Overview application list:

[image: Utilities category in AO]

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20. So is there any way to manually create such categories and change which applications are listed in which ones? This would be very useful.

Comment: Isn't that set up through options in the respective .desktop files?

Comment: @ByteCommander: I don't know, it's new to me... I don't believe there were such categories in 3.18. But maybe they just weren't utilised in such a way.

Comment: You could be right, I don't really see such entries in my .desktop files either, but I'm on Unity... You could check for other config files or dconf settings that might be related.

Comment: @ByteCommander: Nope, nothing in my `.desktop` files, nor do I think this sort of thing would be set in dconf, but maybe, I will have a look. What other config files do you think could have it?

Comment: @ByteCommander: Actually, there do seem to be some settings for it in dconf, but I can't find a way to add new categories, nor does changing settings there seem to make any difference to the applications in the categories. It says that there is no schema associated with the key so I'm not sure if those settings actually work any more, it doesn't really look like it...